# How to implement such a layout?

Tags: css

For a simple chat application, I thought of using this simple layout:

```
*----------------------------------*
|<div>                             |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
+----------------------------------+
|<input type text>            |Send|
+----------------------------------+
```

i.e., at the bottom we have a form consisting of a textfield for typing in messages as well as a button for sending them. The rest of the screen shall be a `<div>` where the messages are shown. The `<div>` should take up the remaining space, and the textfield should stretch horizontally.

My main problem is stretching the div. No matter what I do, it doesn't seem to stretch. I've tried setting `height` to 100%, tried to position is absolute, but didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it the input text field you are having trouble stretching?

Comment: Use position absolute, with bottom:x; where x is the height of the textbox input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place the form inside the div and set them both to absolute, that should do it... This works in Chrome, haven't tested elsewhere:

#### HTML:

```
<div id="convo">
    <form id="talk" method="post" action="#">
        <input type="text" name="talk" />
        <input name="send" id="send" type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
} 

#talk, #convo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border: 4px solid SteelBlue;
}

#talk {
    height: 7.5%;
    bottom: 0;
}

#convo {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: DarkSlateGray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be a sticky footer question (your input is the "footer"):

CSS: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

jQuery: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #container {
                position: relative;
                width: 350px;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: pink;
            }
            #messages {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: blue;
            }
            #controls {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 30px;
                background-color: yellow;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="messages"></div>
            <div id="controls">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {

        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

    }

    #yourdiv {
        width: 200;
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

You can used any one of #youdiv height .